# execute menu command in illustrator with actionscript

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I've seen it in Indesign but can't seem to get it to work in illustrator. If not could anyone tell me how I would group all items together on a layer run a function then ungroup them again. I'm fairlt new to this and struggle with the documentation

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 1):

Execute menu commands is only available from illustrator CS6 onwards